# Python-Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a little issue with webdriver.My machine run windows 7 and successfuly install python and selenium webdriver.Here is the problem
When i run this file

```
from selenium import webdriver
import HTMLTestRunner
import unittest

class nexmo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://wwww.facebook.com")

    def test_login(self):
        emailFieldId = "email"
        el = self.driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldId)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

The test give me
**Ran 0
OK** But the Firefox doesnt start and do the things i tell him.

When I run

```
from selenium import webdriver

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://wwww.facebook.com")
        emailFieldId = "email"
        el = self.driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldId)
        self.driver.quit()
```

Everything is OK.The browser starts and find the element.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'm not sure if you're having formatting issues with the site or if that's your issue... is your if __name__ == '__main__': actually supposed to be part of the class (which is how the indention shows, and would therefore be your problem) or should it be outside (no indentation)  Given you say the test said Ran 0 OK, I'm guessing it's a site formatting issue, but I don't want to edit stuff that turns out to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and copy/pasted it into my Eclipse and it ran fine.

By chance did you re-type this code into SO rather than copy paste?  Is it possible that there is a typo in your "def test_login(self):" line such that unittest can't identify it as a test case?  This is my best guess.  Since unittest first checks to see if you have any unit tests (identified as a function with the pre-fix "test_".  If and only if it finds a test case will it run setUp and tearDown.

Also, the point of unit testing is to actually test that you received a valid value.  Can I recommend adding this to the end of "def test_login":

```
self.assertIsNotNone(el)
```